# MFC: Highlight a line in CRichEditCtrl for some duration and revert back

Tags: c++, mfc

I am pretty new to MFC,C++ programming, Please help me in this issue. 
In an edit box (created with CRichEditCtrl) there are several lines. I need to highlight one line(with red color) for some duration (example: highlight line 1 for 1 second and after that revert back the line color).

How can I do that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can do it using EM_SETCHARFORMAT message: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774230(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

First set your settings like this

`

```
// Select your string (start is the index in characters (not in lines)
GetRichEditCtrl().SetSel( nStart, nStart + nLength);

// Get the CHARFORMAT structure ready
CHARFORMAT cf;
cf.cbSize       = sizeof (cf);
cf.dwEffects    = 0;
cf.dwMask       = CFM_COLOR;
cf.crTextColor = RGB(255,0,0);

GetRichEditCtrl().SetSelectionCharFormat(cf);
```

`

Then create a timer like with `SetTimer(WMT_MYTIMER,1000,NULL)`, override OnTimer, stop the timer with `KillTimer` and reset the color as above

Hope this helps!